# acmsmall breaks line number alignments of algorithms

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx, acm

I am formatting an article with one of the ACM journal formats: acmsmall. However, when I look at algorithms, I noticed that the lines of my algorithm lost their indentation.

This problem does not occur in article class.

I have prepared a minimal example to demostrate the issue.

```
\documentclass{acmsmall}
%\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode} 

\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}
        \caption{MyAlgorithm}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \State $A \gets X$
            \State $A \gets Y$
            \State $A \gets Z$
            \State $A \gets X$
            \State $A \gets Y$
            \State $A \gets Z$
            \State $A \gets X$
            \State $A \gets Y$
            \State $A \gets Z$
            \State $A \gets X$
            \State $A \gets Y$
            \State $A \gets Z$
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

I have attached the screenshots of both acmsmall and article. As you can see, after line 10, the indentation of acmsmall is broken.

How can I fix the problem?

[image: acmsmall]

[image: article]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `acmsmall` class is causing the numbers to be centered rather than right-aligned.  You can correct this by redefining `\alglinenumber` as follows (updated to get fontsize):

```
\newcommand{\myalgnumfont}{\fontsize{8pt}{9pt}\selectfont}
\algrenewcommand{\alglinenumber}[1]{\myalgnumfont #1:}
```

in the preamble.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{acmsmall}
%\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode} 

\newcommand{\myalgnumfont}{\fontsize{8pt}{9pt}\selectfont}
\algrenewcommand{\alglinenumber}[1]{\hss\myalgnumfont #1:}

\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}
        \caption{MyAlgorithm}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \State $A \gets X$
            \State $A \gets Y$
            \State $A \gets Z$
            \State $A \gets X$
            \State $A \gets Y$
            \State $A \gets Z$
            \State $A \gets X$
            \State $A \gets Y$
            \State $A \gets Z$
            \State $A \gets X$
            \State $A \gets Y$
            \State $A \gets Z$
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

The standard `algorithmic` definition use `\footnotesize` to set the fontsize.
The problem is that `acmsmall` redefines the `\footnotesize` to

> ```
> \newcommand{\footnotesize}{%
>     \@setfontsize\footnotesize\@viiipt{9\p@}%
>     \abovedisplayskip 4\p@ \@plus \p@
>     \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
>     \abovedisplayshortskip 4\p@ \@minus \p@
>     \belowdisplayshortskip 4\p@ \@minus \p@
>     \def\@listi{%
>         \leftmargin\leftmargini
>         \topsep 4\p@ \@plus \p@
>         \parsep \z@ \@plus .5\p@
>         \itemsep \p@ \@plus .7\p@}
> }%
> ```

The problem here is the final `\itemsep` which in `size10.clo` loaded by `article.cls` is

> ```
>    \def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
>                \topsep 3\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus\p@
>                \parsep 2\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus\p@
>                \itemsep \parsep}%
> ```

In particular `acmsmall` is adding some glue to the end of `\itemsep`, which then affects the label alignment.

Comment: Do you agree that the new sizing version I posted above does work?

Comment: That works very good. Do we still need the \hss in the \alglinenumber definition?

Comment: No the `\hss` is no longer necessary.  Now deleted from my code.

Comment: How can I get this solution to work if I am using \footnotesize within the algorithm environment?

Comment: @FilippoBistaffa I would be inclined to simply redefine the `\footnotesize` without the extra glue in `\itemsep`.  If that doesn't do what you want, you can ask a new question and provide more details.

Comment: I found that, by moving the `\footnotesize` command from the beginning of the environment to inside the first statement of the algorithm, as in `\State \footnotesize foo`, this solution works.